# Program received Segmentation fault while debug in CLion

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, clion

I have the challenge to implement simplex-method (or simplex algorithm). Simplex-method is a popular algorithm for linear programming which is based on rebuilding matrices. My program should return an optimal solution. I have a C++ project in Clion. It works correctly when I run the program, but during the debug I get a SIGSEGV Signal (Segmentation Fault) in one of the methods. It happens when I try to allocate memory for the matrix. Here is the part of code:

```
double **newTable;
    newTable = new double *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            newTable[i] = new double [cols];
        }
    }
```

I free the memory at the end of the method using delete[], but it doesn’t work. 
I’ve already tried to run the program in another IDE (CodeBlocks), but it works properly too, and I have no idea why it happens and where the problem occurs.

Comment: You have plenty of memory leaks with the code you show, but nothing that could lead to a crash. If you used the debugger in CLion, where in your code does it tell you the crash happens?

Comment: *It works correctly when I run the program, but during the debug I get a SIGSEGV Signal (Segmentation Fault) in one of the methods.* -- Which means that it doesn't work correctly.  Also, we have no idea where, when, or how this code is called, we have no idea the value of `rows` or `cols`, etc.  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I've actually had clion crash in debug mode on allocation as well. Try. Debugging from the command line. If it works (it did for me) its clion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for this nested loop. You only need one loop to allocate memory for this jagged array:

```
int main() {
    int rows = 5, cols = 10;
    double **newTable;
    newTable = new double *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
        newTable[i] = new double[cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        delete newTable[i];
    delete newTable;
}
```

The way your code is now it will leak memory, but that alone won't cause a segmentation fault. There might be a mistake with how you're freeing the memory, too.

---

Also, since this is C++, may I recommend using `std::vector` instead?

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> newTable(5, std::vector<double>(10));
}
```